# A criação de um sinônimo para a tag requer uma pontuação de 5 nesta tag

Tags: suporte, tags-sinônimas

Eu tenho 5 upvotes (votos) nesta resposta:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78599/3635

Fui tentar "sugerir" a tag [regexp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regexp) como sinônimo de [regex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) (sem o p), pois eu vejo sendo mais comum o uso de RegEx (sem p) do que RegExP.

Penso que ambas são usadas com o mesmo proprosito, no entanto no momento que sugeri me apareceu o seguinte erro:

> A criação de um sinônimo para a tag requer uma pontuação de 5 nesta tag.

Acredito que pontuação de 5 seja 5 votos em uma resposta, conforme o link https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/suporte/synonyms:

> Os usuários com reputação de mais de **2500** e uma pontuação total **de respostas** de 5 ou mais na tag podem sugerir sinônimos de tags.

Eu tenho mais de 2500 de reputação e tenho 5 votos em uma resposta cuja a pergunta usa a tal tag (acho que é isto que quer dizer 5 de reputação).

Falta alguma coisa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu acho que você precisa de 5 votos em cada uma das duas tags. É meio burro o sistema. Mas já criei o sinônimo.

> Acho na verdade que o quinto voto veio recentemente, portanto era necessário aguardar que o sistema o contabilizasse. Veja que no perfil dele só constam 4 –  Math
>
> Acontece que o sistema só calcula quantos votos você tem por tag uma vez por dia, à noite. Por isso que eu acho que você não conseguiu sugerir o sinônimo. –  bfavaretto
>
> Recebi o 5 voto em `2015-08-07 13:03:18Z (UTC)`. Ou seja você está certo o calculo ainda não havia "sido efetuado". – Guilherme Nascimento

Comment: Mas eu tenho tecnicamente, pois ambas as tags estão na pergunta.

Comment: Acho na verdade que o quinto voto veio recentemente, portanto era necessário aguardar que o sistema o contabilizasse. Veja que no perfil dele só constam 4: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento?tab=tags&sort=votes&page=2

Comment: Desde quando? Porque o sistema faz cache dessas contagens, deve estar checando o valor em cache e não em tempo real.

Comment: Desde quando o Guilherme tem 5 votos em cada tag. A pergunta era pra ele :P

Comment: @bfavaretto pensei que se eu tive-se duas tags em uma pergunta os votos valiam pra duas tags, no caso como você tornou a outra sinonimo ela sumiu da pergunta.

Comment: @Math deve ser isto, pois eu deveria agora ter "8" em [tag:regex] e "5" em [tag:regexp] (acredito eu), a não ser que eu não tenha entendido o sistema de contagem por tag ainda.

Comment: @bfavaretto Quando puder, poderia me orientar se tiver duas tags em uma pergunta os votos valem só pra uma delas ou pras duas? Obrigado

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Vale para todas as tags da pergunta. Acontece que o sistema só calcula quantos votos você tem por tag uma vez por dia, à noite. Por isso que eu acho que você não conseguiu sugerir o sinônimo.

Comment: @bfavaretto entendi o "desde quando?". Recebi o 5 voto em `2015-08-07 13:03:18Z` (utc). Ou seja você está certo o calculo ainda não havia "sido efetuado". Obrigado!