# Sinonimo de tag requer pontuação mínima

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, tags

Relacionada: [A criação de um sinônimo para a tag requer uma pontuação de 5 nesta tag](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4219/a-cria%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-um-sin%C3%B4nimo-para-a-tag-requer-uma-pontua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-5-nesta-tag)

#### Situação

Recentemente eu fiz [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103444/sped-bloco-k-registro-0220), que não é muito comum aqui no sistema, até porque nem sequer existiam as tags [sped](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sped) e [efd](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/efd). Então as criei, e logo em seguida já atualizei um pouco suas wikis. Contudo, na tag
[efd](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/efd), eu já acharia melhor por o sinônimo [sped-efd](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sped-efd), pois se trata da mesma coisa. Porém, isso daqui me aparece:

> A criação de um sinônimo para a tag requer uma pontuação de 5 nesta tag.

E como diz na pergunta relacionada seriam 5 pontos em cada tag, mas como vou ter isso se recém criei a tag e a outra nem mesmo existe, teria de ser criada também!?

#### Solicitação

Algum usuário que tenha maiores "poderes" que eu fazer este vínculo?

Por favor :D

Comment: Não tem nada a ver com a pergunta mas para já as perguntas dessas tag parecem um bocado fora do âmbito do site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pronto, já criei o sinônimo.